# why below javascript function does not work?

Tags: javascript

I know this is a really silly questions, but just have no idea why this doesn't work:

```
this.getPageName = function(pagenum){

    var name;

    if(pagenum==1){
        this.name='1.page1';
    }
    else if(pagenum==2){
        this.name='2.page2';
    }
    else if(pagenum==3){
        this.name='3.page3';
    }
    else if(pagenum==4){
        this.name='4.page4';
    }
    console.log("pagenum: " + pagenum);
    console.log("tabname: " + name);
    return  name;

}

var page=3;

var pagename=getPageName(page);

console.log(pagename);
```

I suppose `console.log(pagename);` would have `3.page3`, but output is `undefined`.

Anything wrong? there must be some scope error there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the `this.name` inside the function.  It is not referencing the function, but instead the `window` object; that is, `this.name` is not the variable `name` inside the function.

```
this.getPageName = function(pagenum){

    var name;

    if(pagenum==1){
        name='1.page1';
    }
    else if(pagenum==2){
        name='2.page2';
    }
    else if(pagenum==3){
        name='3.page3';
    }
    else if(pagenum==4){
        name='4.page4';
    }
    console.log("pagenum: " + pagenum);
    console.log("tabname: " + name);
    return name;

}

var page=3;

var pagename=getPageName(page);

console.log(pagename);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the keyword `this`.  You defined `name` at the same scope as the rest of the function. That should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

All the `this` is messing you up. Specifically, you're defining the function as `this.getPageName` and then attempting to call the function `getPageName`, which you haven't defined yet - you defined `this.getPageName`. Even if the code does run that way, it's unnecessary. If the `console.log`s inside the function are not executing, then the function isn't running at all.

Then, inside the function, you're referencing `this.name` when `name` alone will do. Remove every instance of `this` from your code and it should work.

You could also tighten up the function by changing your code to this:

```
getPageName = function(pagenum) {
    // Start with '' to make sure it interprets pagenum as a string, not a digit
    var name = '' + pagenum + '.page' + pagenum;

    console.log("pagenum: " + pagenum);
    console.log("tabname: " + name);

    return name;

}
var page=3;
var pagename=getPageName(page);
console.log(pagename);
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use it like an `object`

```
var pagename=new getPageName(page);
console.log(pagename.name);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dR7h/2/)

Or just remove the `this` keyword from all `this.????=''` from inside the function. Also, you can use `var getPageName = function(){ //... };` instead of `this.getPageName`.

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7bTUY/1/)